# How do I fix plt.subplots to bring the plots closer together?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter, subplot

I am plotting 27 maps, or 9 rows and 3 columns. I am using plt.subplots to plot them, but I am struggling to bring the plots closer together? I tried both:

```
plt.tight_layout()  
fig.tight_layout()
```

But I keep getting this error anytime I add that in:

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity
```

This is my code so far with the plt.subplot and mapping, it appears to be working but the map layout is not very readable:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=9, ncols=3,  figsize=(60,44), subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
for i,t,ax in zip(range(27),time_years, axes.ravel()):
    ax.set_extent([-90, 10, 5, 85], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    x = ax.contourf(longitude,latitude,yearly_means[i],10, extend='both')
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, zorder=100, edgecolor='k')
    ax.coastlines()
    gridlines = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
    gridlines.xlabels_top = False
    gridlines.ylabels_right = False
    ax.text(.5,-.11, 'Longitude' , va='bottom' , ha='center', rotation='horizontal', rotation_mode= 'anchor',transform=ax.transAxes)
    ax.text(-.15, .5, 'Latitude' , va='bottom' , ha='center', rotation='vertical', rotation_mode= 'anchor',transform=ax.transAxes)
    ax.set_title('extremes for %d' %t)
cbar = fig.colorbar(x, orientation='horizontal', ax = axes,fraction=.046, pad=0.04)
cbar.set_label('psu', labelpad=15, y=.5, rotation=0)
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=None, hspace=None) # THIS DOES NOT WORK, no change
plt.show()
```

[image]

I tried adding: plt.subplots_adjust to make the width between plots smaller, but there is no difference when I add that line.
How do I bring these plots closer together and make the figures bigger? Also the colorbar overlaps on the image, why might be that happening?

Comment: One of the "problems" is that the projection forces the plots to have a certain aspect ratio. To fit into the given height with that aspect ratio (to avoid deforming the map), their width needs to be rather small.  You could try something like `figsize=(15,44)`. Maybe increase the number of columns?

Comment: `wspace=None` won't don anything.  Try `wspace=0`.  But as @JohanC says, the aspect ratio of your plots is fixed, and your figure width is fixed, so the space has to go somewhere.  To get better colorbar behaviour you can use `constrained_layout` instead of `tight_layout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to try is `plt.tight_layout()` - it will automatically adjust paddings around subplots. Another thing to play with is `figsize` and its aspect ratio to make it consistent with your subplots alignment. In your case, the canvas is too wide for the subplots.

Answer (score 1):

`plt.tight_layout`doesn't remove the padding between the plots automatically but rather fixes overlapping issues.
you can try the pad options described in [plt.tight_layout documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout.html)

what will probably work better/best is to use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(9,3, figsize=(9,6), layout="compressed")`
with emphasis on `layout="compressed"` which should help in your case of maps/ images [layout=compressed](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/arranging_axes.html#grids-of-fixed-aspect-ratio-axes)